# Problems with CSS styling in PHP code

Tags: php, html, css, colors, styles

First of all, I am very new to PHP, so there might be some noob mistake.
Anyways;

I have a goal here, which is making a table which is basically a calendar. And then I want the cell in the table that corresponds to the current day, to have red text. That is all. But it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
<table border="1" id="calendar">

        <caption><h1>September</h1></caption>
        <?php



            $currentDate = (int)date("d");
            $currentMonth = (int)date("m");
            $currentMonthL = date("L");
            $columnsInRow = 7;
            $daysInMonth = date("t");

            $currentDay = 1;
                for ($i=0 ; $i < $daysInMonth ; $i++) {
                    ECHO '<tr class="cal">';
                        for ($j=0 ; $j < $columnsInRow && $currentDay <= $daysInMonth ; $j++) {
                            ECHO var_dump($currentDay);
                            ECHO var_dump($currentDate);
                            if(currentDate==currentDay) {
                                ECHO '<div style="height:150%;width:100%text-decoration:none;"><td class="cal"><a href="date_info.php?currentDay=' . $currentDay . '"><h2 style"color:red;">' . $currentDay . '</h2></a></td></div>';
                                $currentDay++;
                            }else{
                                ECHO '<div style="height:150%;width:100%text-decoration:none;"><td class="cal"><a href="date_info.php?currentDay=' . $currentDay . '"><h2 style="color:#554100;">' . $currentDay . '</h2></a></td></div>';
                                $currentDay++;                              
                            }
                        }
                    ECHO '</tr>';
                }           
        ?>

    </table>
```

This is what it gives me (note that the current day is NOT red):

[image]

Thankyou in advance

Comment: You apply CSS to your HTML, not your PHP. Look at the HTML you are generating. Is it what you expect? It certainly isn't valid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: You are missing = in style"color:red;"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two problems in you code.

First one in php if clause that `if(currentDate==currentDay)` needs to be corrected to `if($currentDate == $currentDay)`.

And second one in css markup that `<h2 style"color:red;">`  has to be corrected to `<h2 style="color:red;">`.

Hope this helps

Comment: While that will produce the proper markup, the conditional still won't fire.

Comment: Ok but it is a problem too.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple, actually.

You're not actually comparingyour variables. Look closely.

```
if(currentDate===currentDay)
```

Should be

```
if($currentDate===$currentDay)
```

[Here's an eval.in illustrating this](https://eval.in/199643)

Comment: `if(currentDate===currentDay)` is nowhere in the code and without css correction will still not fire red color.

Comment: @emmanuel Are you blind? `if(currentDate==currentDay) {
                                ECHO '<div ` look again.

Comment: I don't think so, check (==) instead of (===).

Comment: @emmanuel No, The `directly equals to comparison` is fine. I'm not sure how you're not seeing that comparing two constants that have never been  declared won't work. Please just stop.

Comment: ok deal but in OP code there are 2 = instead of 3 = in your code.